# Maven, Spring Initializr and Eclipse: How do I set a single main class?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, maven

I created a spring maven project with spring initializr, which generated following pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring-docker-test</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-docker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-docker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Then I unzipped the generated zip file, imported it into Eclipse, and set the goal of the project to `spring-boot:run`

I also added a project as described [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)

In `src/main/java/hello/Application.java`

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public String home() {
    return "Hello Docker World";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

Now when I try to "Run As > Maven build", I get the following error message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.8:run (default-cli) on project spring-boot-docker: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.8:run failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [hello.Application, com.springdockertest.springbootdocker.SpringBootDockerApplication] -> [Help 1]
```

How do I set a single main class (in the `pom.xml` file?)

Answer (score 2):

You can set it by adding `<configuration>` to your pom.xml’s declaration of Boot’s Maven plugin:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>             
            <configuration>    
                <mainClass>hello.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: thank you very much. May I ask some questions? First, is this best practice to handle such a spring initializr generated archive? I mean, to add an own project and then manually add it to `pom.xml` ? Also, *how many own* packages/projects per Maven - what is it? Also a project? - is one supposed to add? Just one? Second: How come the target name is `spring-boot-docker-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and not, as stated in the tutorial, `gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar`. It also states that on terminal the command would be `./mvnw package && java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar`

Comment: Didn't I chose the right phase / goal with `docker-boot:run` maybe?